# React Native fingerprint authentication for android and ios both

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-fingerprint-api

I have built an android app using fingerprint authentication in Android Studio. I need to build the same thing but using React Native for android and iOS. How to go for it?

Comment: check out [Integrate Touch ID and Face ID to your React Native App](https://medium.com/react-native-training/integrate-touch-id-and-face-id-to-your-react-native-app-707e7db17edc)

Answer (score 3):

`react-native-touch-id` is no longer maintained.

Better use

[RN-Fingerprint-Scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner)

Also, If you are using `Expo-cli`

you can alternatively use

[Expo Local Authentication](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-local-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library.

This library supports face and touch identification on both iOS and Android.
But it clearly said for android its experimental, but I didn't faced any problem for android.

Also it blocks too many requests which is nice feature to have, provides good documentation.

- [react-native-touch-id](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id) github
- [react-native-touch-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-id) npmjs

Answer (score 0):

- react-native-fingerprint-scanner: This package provides a simple JavaScript API for accessing fingerprint scanners on both Android and iOS devices.
- react-native-touch-id: This package allows you to use Touch ID for authentication in your React Native app. It supports both iOS and Android.
- react-native-fingerprint-android: This package provides a simple API for using the fingerprint scanner on Android devices.
- react-native-biometric: A library for React Native that provides a consistent API for biometric authentication on both Android and iOS.